# Drawing a Rectangle with color and thickness in OnGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to draw a frame / rectangle in OnGUI in order to display a certain area for debugging purposes.

This rectangle should be displayed with a certain "thickness" / line width and color.

So far, I have only found GUI.Label and GUI.Box, which both seems inadequate for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use OnGui. It is old and terrible. Use the new UI (UGUI).

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for debugging I would recommend to use [Gizmos.DrawWireCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawWireCube.html)

**Note**: Only drawn in the `SceneView` **not** in the `GameView` so really **only** for debugging

```c#
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    // Draw a yellow cube at the transform position
    var color = Gizmos.color;
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
    Gizmos.color = color;
}
```

for showing it only if object is selected or `OnDrawGizmos` for showing it allways

Note that this is done in WorldSpace so if you rather want the size vector etc rotate together with the object you can wrap in between

```c#
var matrix = Gizmos.matrix;
Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

//...

Gizmos.matrix = matrix;
```

---

Unfortunately there is no option to change the line thikness...

... **but** you could overcome this by simply drawing e.g. 4 normal cubes using [Gizmos.DrawCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawCube.html) to form a rectangle. Something maybe like

```c#
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    DrawDebugRect(new Vector2(0.5f, 0.3f), 0.05f);
}

private void DrawRect(Vector2 size, float thikness)
{   
    var matrix = Gizmos.matrix;
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

    //top cube
    Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.up * size.y / 2, new Vector3(size.x, thikness, 0.01f);

    //bottom cube
    Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.down * size.y / 2, new Vector3(size.x, thikness, 0.01f);

    //left cube
    Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.left * size.x / 2, new Vector3(thikness, size.y, 0.01f);

    //right cube
    Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.right * size.x / 2, new Vector3(thikness, size.y, 0.01f);

    Gizmos.matrix = matrix;
}
```

---

I'm only on smartphone so it might not be copy-past-able but I think you'll get the idea ;)